# declare arrow function in the class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have created class like below. Is there something wrong with following? I just followed others' way but it continuously gives me, 'Test run failure: file script.js has invalid syntax​​'. I have searched very hard, I do not think there is any exceptions from them. Could you give some advice for this?

```
class AAA {
   constructor(value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   add = a => value + a;
}
```

Comment: You can't have assignments inside the class body. What's wrong with the method syntax: `add(a) { return this.value + a; }`? The arrow function won't work anyway, because you need `this` to access the `value`, which arrow functions can't do.

Comment: You can’t do this yet without a transpiler.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I just changed into regular function definition. It looked like React component uses that way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign in the class body. You can do it in the constructor or you could use TypeScript.

```js
class AAA {
   constructor(value) {
     this.value = value;
     
     this.add = a => this.value + a;
   }
}


let aaa = new AAA(5);

console.log(aaa.add(5));
```